# Any alternatives to jQuery UI in 2021?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

So the possible duplicates to this question that got shown to me here are from 2009-2012.

I'm currently working on a project that would benefit from the jQuery UI `.draggable()` and `.resizable()` methods and is also currently using jQuery core.
But after doing some digging into the Repository and Website, jQUI seems basically dead to me (Latest supported stable is jQ 1.13 and we're at Core 3.5.* by now).

Are there any recent frameworks for mimicking this functionality - best as easy as it seemed with jQUI and not using Vue, Angular or React (as this would way overshoot my scope here)?

Maybe some useful information about the project:

- Using Bootstrap 4.6
- Using jQuery Core 3.4.1

Comment: `1.13` vs `3.5` - the jquery-ui version numbers have never been in sync with the jquery versions.   Don't see "3.5" and expect a "3.x" version of jquery ui.

Comment: So you mean that 1.13 is supporting the latest jQ core?

Comment: [https://jqueryui.com/](https://jqueryui.com/) "*Compatibility with recent jQuery versions (up to 3.6)*" provides more details

Comment: Thank you for the info. Seems like I overlooked this info in my pass through the docs.